# Generating a 2d mesh file from points

Tags: python-3.x, mesh

I have to generate a 2d mesh in a format compatible with [optimesh](https://pypi.org/project/optimesh/), in order to refine it with the algorithms included in that library, (in particular Centroidal Voronoi tesselation smoothing). I'm starting from a set of unordered points, so I'm trying to understand which is the easiest chain of tools to do the job.I have no familiarity at all with geometry processing, so forgive me if my questions are stupid.

I found a lot of libraries to process a mesh from a file in a huge variety of format, but I'm missing how to generate it from points.
I've seen that with scipy I can get a triangulation, but the object returning from scipy, can't be fed directly to optimesh.

So, my problem now is basically something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay,delaunay_plot_2d


points = np.random.random((100,2))
delaun = Delaunay(points)

#Magic code that I wish
delaun.to_meshfile('meshfile.xxx')  
#
```

with a file format that i can process later with optimesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[optimesh](https://github.com/nschloe/optimesh) author here. Your `delaun` object has `delaun.points` and `delaun.simplices`. Those can be fed into optimesh:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay, delaunay_plot_2d
import optimesh

points = np.random.random((100, 2))
delaun = Delaunay(points)

points, cells = optimesh.cvt.quasi_newton_uniform_blocks(
    delaun.points, delaun.simplices, tol=1.0e-5, max_num_steps=100
)
```

If you really want to store them in a file, check out [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio).